# Какая нужна директива для использования ToList

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

Есть фрагмент кода

```
List<IWebElement> SearchTexts = Browser.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#layout-content div.orchard-layouts-root p")).ToList();
```

Выпадает такая ошибка

Ошибка  CS1061  "IWebElement" не содержит определения для "ToList", и не удалось найти доступный метод расширения "ToList", принимающий тип "IWebElement" в качестве первого аргумента (возможно, пропущена директива using или ссылка на сборку).

Вот используемые директивы:

```
using NUnit.Framework;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq
```

Comment: Метод `FindElement` возвращает один элемент. Возможно, вам нужен метод `FindElements` (s на конце).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Прошу прощения, не правильно написал, ошибка был

```
 Browser.FindElement
```

Правильно

```
 Browser.FindElements
```

Comment: @alexanderbarakin Нет, это именно ответ, см. комментарий под вопросом: Find Element возвращает элемент Т, а Find Elements возвращает IEnumerable<T> - и проблема была именно в этом, т.к. .ToList есть у IEnumerable, а не у элемента.